# abstract Iterator for indexable colletions

Tags: java, indexing, iterator, abstract-class

My framework is full of iterators like

```
int n = col.getSize();
for (int i = 0 ; i != n; i++) {
  Type obj = col.get(i);
```

And, I feel that every program that iterates items over the index has a piece of code like this. It feels ugly compared to the neat foreach

```
for (Type obj : col) {
```

Transition to foreach requires making all the collections Iterable, which means creating a new Iterator in every iterator() method. Now, I had the ugly code in every collection declaration instead of its use places. So, I did the a good job, I moved the ugly code into the common.utils.

```
public abstract class ImmutableIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private int i = 0; 
    private final int size = getSize();

    public abstract int getSize();  // to be implemented by user
    public abstract T getValue(int i); // to be implemented by user

    public T next() { 
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException(); 
        return getValue(i++);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() { return i != size;}

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove is not implemented");
    }
}
```

Now, I have isolated this ugly pattern in only place. This is the best I could do. The collections will supply the size and value(i). The only problem is performance penaly: I have to do the size check twice in the loop, first for hasNext and another in the next(). I wonder why Sun does not provide such a class? It is needed to everybody. Have I just overlooked it?

Comment: *I wonder why Sun does not provide such a class? It is needed to everybody. Have I just overlooked it?* You realize that all standard collections already implement `Iterable`, right?  Thus it's not "needed by everybody"; I've never needed it, ever, because I don't write my own collection classes, I use predefined ones.

Comment: You went through all this refactoring only to get rid of basic `for` statements? What kind of collections are you using?

Comment: A total aside: Java has a standard exception type for when an operation isn't supported: `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: Actually, this implementation is only usable for lists, and all the JDK lists (or at least, many of them) extend AbstractList, which defines an iterator implementation (overridden when necessary)

Comment: @Mark Peters, I have got the answer that Guava provides exactly what I want. Why? Do you understand that everybody uses Iterable and standard collections?

Comment: @MarkPeters Based on the example and my personal experience I'd venture to guess the OP could be working with Swing models.  Take a look at [TableColumnModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html), for example.  It's a "collection" of sorts, but it doesn't implement `Iterable`...which is something that's always kinda bothered me about Swing

Comment: @Val: Guava has an iterator class because it provides its own collections. I agree with Mark Peters: I can't remember having implemented an iterator() method in years. And if I have, I probably simply delegated to an internal standard or Guava collection to implement it. Maybe you should explain why you need to implement your own collections.

Comment: @JB Nizet I need them because somebody decided that providing direct access to your collections is bad thing and you must hide the collections behind the getSize/getItem(i) decorator! This is a good Java practice!

Comment: And what prevents you from implementing the `iterator()` method this way: `return Collections.unmodifiableList(myPrivateNonExposedInternalList).iterator();`?

Comment: @Val: You said you were hiding a **collection** behind a decorator, which means that this decorator could return the iterator of the collection as I just explained, since **every** collection has an iterator.

Comment: @JB Nizet Ok, this is another acceptable answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomasz Nurkiewicz directed us to the Guava's `UnmodifiableIterator`. But, only remove method is defined there whereas we want the index iteration also. This hint allowed LouisWasserman to find out a better solution: the `AbstractIndexedListIterator` does what we want. The only drawback is that this class does not implement the remove method and is closed in the Guava package. All this tells us that such classes are really useful but must be implemented by the user in his framework.

JB Nizet proposed another solution. Instead of implementing the iterator interface on top of getSize/GetItem(idx) methods, we can return one retreived from the underlying collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is so little code to be shared here in an abstract class, so that the abstraction adds little benefit. I figure it is just as easy to just implement such an iterator from scratch in every collection. In many cases, `hasNext` can probably be implemented more direct, for example.

See, your abstract class has about as many abstract lines as it has non-abstract code lines. Now, many classes may want to implement mutable iterators, then virtually nothing remains in your abstract class.

Plus, **it will never need to change**. Abstract classes are in particular great if this allows you to make changes such as bug fixes once, and fix a number of classes at the same time. However, this code is so simple, what is going to be this bug? The "throws" in "remove" for example can barely have a bug - it should never be executed. There is no benefit at all from sharing this across multiple iterators.

Comment: How do you count? I have only two abstract lines of code and 10 reused: initialize i, initialize size, i++, i == size checks, throw two exeptions -- all things to be copy-pasted every time. Right? May be good designers think that copy-paste is a good programming practice, But bad advisers tell me that this saves me a lot of typing time, places to make a bug and ease of code adjustment.

Comment: I'm not counting lines my IDE will generate on the fly. So I count 1 line for the "remove" method, 1 line for the "size" method. etc.

Comment: The lines you are talking about is just garbage that I do not want to see in my code. There are 7 statements that IDE will not generate you.

The lines you are talking about is just garbage that I do not want to see in my code. There are 7 statements that IDE will not generate you.

The lines you are talking about is just garbage that I do not want to see in my code. There are 7 statements that IDE will not generate you.

The lines you are talking about is just garbage that I do not want to see in my code. There are 7 statements that IDE will not generate you.

Comment: These 7 statements, copy-pasted all over the place, will evict the code from your processor cache and need maintainance. For the latter reason, programmers share every possible bit of code, no matter how simple it is. Haskell introduces map function for the 4-statement procedure `f x : map f xs`. Mine pattern is more complex. Yet, you do promote garbage coding and remove the comments. All dirty things.

Comment: Well, obviously the Java classpath writers differ, and see no use in the code sharing for Iterators. For example, HotSpot might be better capable of inlining a standalone `Iterator`, that does not share code with other iterators. So either they missed this obvious chance of sharing code (hmm.. they do have various abstract collection classes!) - or they have had reasons to *not* do this.